# Is use of 'in' more efficient in hibernate query?

Tags: hibernate

Is use of `in` is more efficient in hibernate query? I can substitute it with looping with multiple `or` clauses.

Comment: depends on the DB you are using... and your indexes

Answer (score 1):

in
is always efficient as compare to looping with or conditions. Also depends on the column which you are applying it is of numeric or text and indexing on that column.